# Minify Angular 2 with Webpack

Tags: angular, uglifyjs

Running UglifyJs on an Angular 2 app, I receive the error message

> `Can't bind to 'ngforOf' since it isn't a known property of 'a'`

Here are some excerpts from configs:

```
module: {
    preLoaders: [{
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'tslint'
    }] ...

plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
        mangle: {
            keep_fnames: true
        }
    })...

htmlLoader: {
    minimize: false // workaround for ng2
}
```

In template casing is correct - it is `ngFor`, with capital ­'F` - apparently UglifyJs is lowercasing it ?

`a(*ngFor='let language of languageList', (click)='selectLanguage(language)') {{language}}`

Comment: Use `*ngFor` instead of `*ngfor` in your template.

Comment: @RolandRácz: jade template has correct case:
`a(*ngFor='let language of languageList', (click)='selectLanguage(language)') {{ language }}`

Comment: Is it working if you set `mangle` to `false`? https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#no-mangling

Comment: unfortunately (here I need to get till SO' required minimal comment length) - no

Comment: Try `htmlLoader: { minimize: false, caseSensitive: true }`. I hope it helps.

Comment: Or check this thread if you have not done it yet: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618 There are a few possible solutions in the comments. I don't know which one should work in your case.

Comment: yet still doesn't

Comment: Do you have any additional parameter to your `npm run build`? How do you run your build?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165199/discussion-between-avj-and-roland-racz).